# AWS Lambda: error creating the event source mapping: Configuration is ambiguously defined

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

> There was an error creating the event source mapping: Configuration is ambiguously defined. Cannot have overlapping suffixes in two rules if the prefixes are overlapping for the same event type.

I created an event earlier from the GUI console 6-7 days ago and it was working fine. The next day the event just missing, i cant see it anymore at the Lambda console GUI. But every S3 objects still seems triggering the lambda function not a problem.   If i cant see, it is not good; So i deleted the Lambda function, waited for 5-10 seconds before creating another new function. And now, i receive the same above when i try to create the event sources like this:
[image]

When i click "Submit" the event sources tab says "You do not have any event sources for this function", Lambda does not get triggered; it means the entire application flow is now broken  :(

The problem is almost the same as: "https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=670712" But somehow i cant reply to that thread, so i created a new thread here instead. anyone encounter this issue?

In fact, i try to response to the existing AWS forum thread: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=670712&#670712
but i keep getting this funny error: "Your message quota has been reached. Please try again later.". And i wasnt even posting anything, how can i use up my quota?

Comment: How are you setting up the event rule on your S3 bucket?  Can you share the rules you have set?

Comment: @James, sure, updating the description with the even rule

Comment: @Reusable that "quota has been reached" error is irritating.

Answer (score 161):

What I suspect is your S3 bucket may still be "linked" to the lambda function.

Maybe check your S3 bucket for events and remove them there, then try creating the lambda events again?
i.e. S3 bucket-> properties-> Events

After 6 years nice to see some people still befitting from this answer,
Here is a shamless plug to youtube video I uploaded 2022-12-13.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rjpOU7jbgEs

Comment: Impossible to just guess how to solve that problem. The error message is really not helpful on the Amazon Lambda console. Thanks @Ridwaan-Manuel

Comment: When I deleted a lambda function, it didn't delete the trigger for whatever reason causing this bug..

Comment: This is correct, it will keep failing unless you delete the notification for that event from S3 bucket-> properties-> Events. This is definitively the correct answer.

Comment: It workied for me. I went there and I removed linked events

Comment: Yes! Trigger wasn't showing in designer, but in S3. Removed with this method and can instantly re-attach trigger.  I thought it was an issue deploying a Template twice with similar names (Cf1 vs. CF1) by accident.

Answer (score 5):

The issue must be that the s3 bucket is already linked with the suffix/prefix you are trying to link. Remove the link in S3 and try again.

Comment: you can give suggestion in comments

Comment: @RatanUdayKumar Not with the reputation of 1. https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment

Comment: given you reputation

Answer (score 1):

When you setup a lambda function and setup a trigger related to S3. The notification gets updated in the properties sections of that S3 bucket.

The mentioned error occurs when the earlier lambda function is deleted and you're trying to setup same kind of trigger again. This time the thing to note is, the S3 notification is still not deleted when you deleted the lambda function.

Goto S3 bucket > Properties > Event notifications
and delete the old setting and then setup new trigger in the new lambda function trigger.

Answer (score 0):

Go to S3 bucket and go to event section. Delete the old event which is attached to other Lambda and you are good to create a new trigger.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you've previously set up a trigger event for this S3 bucket, and even though you've deleted the associated Lambda functions, the event notification in the S3 bucket's settings wasn't removed. As a result, when you attempt to set up a new trigger event for the same bucket and prefix, you encounter an error due to this ambiguity.

Please follow these steps to resolved this issues:

1. Navigate to your S3 bucket.
2. Go to `Properties` and locate the `Event notifications` section.
3. Identify and delete the existing event notification associated with the Lambda function or destination you want to remove.
4. After deleting the event, try setting up the trigger again with the same S3 bucket and prefix.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a link to a youtube video profiling this issue and demonstrating the solution: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1Tfmc9nEtbU

Just as Ridwaan Manuel, you must remove the events by going to S3 bucket-> properties-> Events as the video shows.

Steps to reproduce this issue:

1. Create a bucket and create a folder called “example/”
2. Create Lambda Function
3. Add S3 trigger to the lambda using the bucket from (1) with default settings
4. Save the trigger
5. Click Save and notice error
6. Refresh the page and notice that the triggers disappeared
7. Add the same bucket again and notice the ambiguous reference error